# PHP - Converting a regular function to inline anonymous function

Tags: php, anonymous-function

This is my function:

```
function rp_md5 ($string)
{
    return md5(strrev($string) . $string);
}
```

I wish to convert it to a inline anonymous function and I have already tried this code:

```
$foo = $_POST['u_pwd'];
$pwd = function() use($foo) { 
                return md5(strrev($foo) . $foo);
     };
```

How I can store new password in the variable `$pwd`?
normally I must call it:

```
echo $pwd($foo);
```

sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: What do you expect about `use($foo)` ?

Comment: What's the point of the `use`? Why not simply `$pwd=function($foo) {return md5(strrev($foo) . $foo);};`

Comment: he does expect $foo to be global variable I guess

Comment: You can't store the password created by the function `$pwd` in the variable `$pwd` if your function is already called `$pwd` without losing that function definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you might expect is that you are trying directly to print `$pwd` as a variable, instead as a function. This way `$pwd` will be object of class Closure and cannot be converted to string. You should CALL it.

In your example it will be:

```
$foo='adasdsadasd';
$pwd=function() use($foo) {return md5(strrev($foo) . $foo);};
echo $pwd();
```

returning

> c22ddae767082a65351481607d0974b7

but with `use($foo)` you expect $foo to be a global variable, your function is barely reusable.

Using:

```
$foo='adasdsadasd';
$pwd=function($foo) {return md5(strrev($foo) . $foo);};
```

will give you the opportunity to call `$pwd()` with parameters, so you can use it everytime with different param.

In this case you are using:

```
echo $pwd($foo);
```

To achieve the same output:

> c22ddae767082a65351481607d0974b7

Comment: please recheck my question

Comment: @progfa You must call it `$pwd()` (if there is use($foo)) or `$pwd($foo)`. What do you need? One more assignation? `$foo='adasdsadasd';
$pwd=function($foo) {return md5(strrev($foo) . $foo);};
$pwd1 = $pwd($foo);
echo $pwd1;`

Comment: I want to do it without calling $pwd($foo) and new password must be store in the same variable($pwd), it is not possible?

Comment: @progfa  If you don't want to CALL why do you use a CALLABLE then? `$pwd = md5(strrev($foo) . $foo)` is pretty much straightforward for the concept you want to achieve. Otherwise it's not possible to get return value of function (whether closure or not) without calling it